# find_parent() method implementation - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

`find_parent()` method is different from `find_parents()` method because it returns the first immediate parent, unlike `find_parents()` which returns the entire matching parent tags. But why this code is supposed to be correct?

```
print(soup.a.string.find_parent("p"))
```

given :

```
   <p>
     <a>"...."</a>
   </p>
```

p isn't the immediate parent of the string.

Answer (score 2):

`parents` means ancestor, `find_parent("p")` means find the first ancestor which name is `p`

```
In [5]: soup.a.string.parents
Out[5]: <generator object parents at 0x7f2ee14558e0>

In [6]: list(_)
Out[6]: 
[<a>"...."</a>, <p>
 <a>"...."</a>
 </p>, <body><p>
 <a>"...."</a>
 </p></body>, <html><body><p>
 <a>"...."</a>
 </p></body></html>, <html><body><p>
 <a>"...."</a>
 </p></body></html>]

In [7]: for a in soup.a.string.parents:
   ...:     if a.name == "p":
   ...:         print(a)
   ...:         break
   ...:     
<p>
<a>"...."</a>
</p>
```